# What is the problem with this flutter code. Im trying to read the data from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

```
Future<Object?> GetData() async {
  FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("litre");

// Get the data once
  DatabaseEvent event = await ref.once();

// Print the data of the snapshot
  print(event.snapshot.value);
  return event.snapshot.value;
}
```

Code is here I want to get the value of "litre" tag and then print it into Text() function.
Firebase json is here =>

```
{
    "litre": "16"
}
```

And I expected to see "16" but I facing Instance of 'Future'

Comment: You have to provide some logs or error stacks. Or explain what output you're getting instead of what you expected.

Comment: As @AbdullahZKhan said, what problem are you facing and please add a snapshot of your firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetData` is an async function, so using it in a `Text()` widget will throw an exception because it is not string.

You can use `FutureBuilder` to build the `Text()` widget.

Example:

```
Otherwidgets,
FutureBuilder(
          future: GetData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) => Text(snapshot.data.toString()),
        ),
```

Comment: can you show me how to use futurebuilder with text widget if you have time?